# How to Set react Js constant from php code

Tags: php, reactjs

i m using a custom php application that uses react js as frontend ,so my issue is that i want to set a constant imaagePath in react js that is generated by a php file ,its a dynamic url that is fetched from db

React js code

```
export const imagesPath = some image path from php code;
```

PHP code

```
<?php

include_once("gateway/services/db/DataSource.php");
$dbConn = new DataSource(); // constructor configures mysql

error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Config
{
    static function get($configId)
    {
        $sql = "select CFG_ID, VALUE, DESCRIPTION from cfg where CFG_ID IN ('" . $configId . "');";
        $cfgResult = mysql_query($sql);
        $num_cfgResults = mysql_num_rows($cfgResult);
        if ($num_cfgResults < 1) {
            return null;
        }
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($cfgResult);
       return $imagepath="https//www.example.com/".$row["VALUE"].";

    }

    static function getGuid()
    {
        $guid = self::get(341);
        if ((!$guid) || ($guid == 'this-has-not-been-set-yet')) {
            throw new Exception('GUID is not defined');
        }
        return $guid;
    }
}
```

i want to import php image path into react js constant.js
Note:constant.js is used evrywhere
i m new to react js

Comment: PHP can assign values to JavaScript either through the JSON response to the React API request or by placing constants in a script tag before React's script tag if you have an initial HTML returned from PHP before React starts. Alternatively, a more efficient approach could be to create a static route that manages the dynamic content on the server side. This allows for better control and manipulation of the data passed between PHP and JavaScript in your application.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on more details how your app is working.

1. Your PHP BE is running on the server and values of its properties must be shared only by a HTTP Response (if talking about HTTP requests). This response can be standard html response, plaintext, json etc.
2. JS is running in the browser since it's its interpret. React takes its information by making HTTP requests (probably Fetch API of the browser) to the server.

Therefore I'd say the only way how you can import some data from BE into FE is via an endpoint that will return HTTP Response with your value. Then React will process it and set it as a state variable.

**Template Rendering**

If you are using some MVC framework, you use a PHP `render` function (like twig, ginger, latte, ...). This render function can take arguments and you can set them in `dataset` of your element.

HTML and dataset (data- attributes) are the easiest way. But if all your HTML is built by JS, then the PHP variables are already gone by that time, then you have to ask for them at some endpoint. Then you should also think of security and if some information can be abused.